# Mosaicplot. Passing value to mosaic bars

Tags: r

I am very new to R so would gladly take any advice.
So I have a data frame like this:

```
     Year   Age     POF values
1  2019K1 15–24    town   10.8
2  2020K1 15–24    town   12.3
3  2021K1 15–24    town   11.6
4  2022K1 15–24    town   11.8
5  2019K1 25–54    town    5.1
6  2020K1 25–54    town    5.2
7  2021K1 25–54    town    6.2
8  2022K1 25–54    town    5.3
9  2019K1 55–64    town    6.6
10 2020K1 55–64    town    7.7
11 2021K1 55–64    town    7.9
12 2022K1 55–64    town    7.1
13 2019K1 15–24 village   15.0
14 2020K1 15–24 village   19.7
15 2021K1 15–24 village   14.1
16 2022K1 15–24 village   13.9
17 2019K1 25–54 village    7.8
18 2020K1 25–54 village    8.5
19 2021K1 25–54 village    8.0
20 2022K1 25–54 village    6.0
21 2019K1 55–64 village    9.3
22 2020K1 55–64 village   11.5
23 2021K1 55–64 village   12.8
24 2022K1 55–64 village   10.1
```

and I've been trying to plot it as mosaic, but I can't figure out why doesn't my mosaic take values from the data frame and apply them to bars based on data frame given.

this is my plot code:

```
mosaicplot(~ data$Year + data$Age + data$POF, data = data)
```

And this is how the plot ends up looking:

[Mosaicplot using code demo given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFKJk.png)

and the mosaicplot bars don't represent the values. What am I doing wrong?

dput:

```
structure(list(Year = c("2019K1", "2020K1", "2021K1", "2022K1", 
"2019K1", "2020K1", "2021K1", "2022K1", "2019K1", "2020K1", "2021K1", 
"2022K1", "2019K1", "2020K1", "2021K1", "2022K1", "2019K1", "2020K1", 
"2021K1", "2022K1", "2019K1", "2020K1", "2021K1", "2022K1"), 
    Age = c("15–24", "15–24", "15–24", "15–24", "25–54", "25–54", 
    "25–54", "25–54", "55–64", "55–64", "55–64", "55–64", "15–24", 
    "15–24", "15–24", "15–24", "25–54", "25–54", "25–54", "25–54", 
    "55–64", "55–64", "55–64", "55–64"), POF = c("town", "town", 
    "town", "town", "town", "town", "town", "town", "town", "town", 
    "town", "town", "village", "village", "village", "village", 
    "village", "village", "village", "village", "village", "village", 
    "village", "village"), values = c(10.8, 12.3, 11.6, 11.8, 
    5.1, 5.2, 6.2, 5.3, 6.6, 7.7, 7.9, 7.1, 15, 19.7, 14.1, 13.9, 
    7.8, 8.5, 8, 6, 9.3, 11.5, 12.8, 10.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: why would it? you don't reference it in the call. plus a mosaic plot is made from a contingency table, not continuous data. and also you should not use `$` notation when using a `data = ` argument

Comment: @Quinten I've added dput data above in main post text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the formula version of `moasicplot` will count the number of observations in the groups defined by your categorical variables. It has no idea you want to use the `values` column for the values.

Alternatively you can use the table version of `mosaicplot` so you can turn your data into a table object with the specific values you want to use in your plot. Here's how you would do that with your data

```
mosaicplot(xtabs(values~Year+Age+POF, data=data))
```

[image]